# What to do with a key hashed line is too long for rubocop?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Rubocop says this line is too long

```
if paragraph.update(picture:
  contact_params[:menucontact_attributes][:paragraphs_attributes]['0'][:picture])
```

How can I split `contact_params[:menucontact_attributes][:paragraphs_attributes]['0'][:picture])` into multiple lines?

Comment: maybe have `menu_attrs = contact_params[:menucontact_attributes]` and then use `menu_attrs[:paragraphs_attributes]['0'][:picture]`

Comment: or similarly `para_attrs = contact_params[:menucontact_attributes][:paragraphs_attributes]['0']`

Comment: Is using `update!` and a `rescue` an option here? That avoids the `if` part which Rubocop has a whole bunch of rules about. I find that approach generally leads to cleaner code as your "exceptional" code is at the end of the method and the default behaviour isn't indented or special.

Comment: Is "nothing" a valid answer to the question in the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for (Ruby 2.3+)

```
contact_params.dig(
  :menucontact_attributes,
  :paragraphs_attributes,
  '0',
  :picture
)
```

Keep in mind that unlike your version, this won't blow up if any of these attributes is not present.

Comment: That's part of it, but you'll need to format the `update` call as well to get Rubocop to stand down.

Comment: Correct, I've stuck to the hash part as I don't know how OP's Rubocop is configured exactly.

Comment: The big problem here is it's within the context of an `if` and Rubocop gets kind of snippy if you make those multiple lines. Assigning this to a temporary variable that you can test might be the trick.

Comment: Presumably, the coder exoects an exception to be raised if any of the nested keys are not present. One could raise the exception in the called method if `dig` passes `nil`, but that's a bit messy. As well, the use of`dig` is problematic when `nil` is a valid return value.

Comment: That's perfect! just assigning `contact_params.dig(...)` to a variable as tadmand suggest and passing this variable to the `update`